# How to make ensure that the generated value from an equation with random variables falls within a selected range

Tags: excel

[image]

I need to make sure that value in N3 is around the selected value in K3. I am not sure how to do it as the value in N3 is made of random variable from L4 and L3.

Code for L3
`=RANDBETWEEN(1,31)`

Code for L4
`=RANDBETWEEN(L3+1,32)`

Code for M3
`=INDEX(F5:F36,L3)`

Code for M4
`=INDEX(F5:F36,L4)`

Code for N3
`=((M4/M3)^(1/(L4-L3))-1)`

Comment: You should use VBA to do this.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to do it without VBA?

Comment: because I don't have experience with it but, so I am not sure how to do it in VBA